# Background image is not working after deploying MVC4 application it in IIS

Tags: css, .net, html, asp.net-mvc-4

i had a website developed in MVC4 and everything was working fine until i deploy it in iis.After deploying background image is not loading at all

```
<style>
        .testt {
            background-image: url("../../Images/master/background-Mid.bmp");
            width: 100%;
            height: 100px;
        }
    </style>

</head>
<body>    
 <header style="position: relative; top: -20px ">
     <div class="testt">

        <div style="float:right;width:20%;margin-right:10%"><img src="~/Images/master/Right.bmp" /></div>
        <div style="float:right;width:5%"> <img src="~/Images/master/tstLogo.gif"/></div>
      <div style="float:left;width:5%"> <img src="~/Images/master/Left.bmp" /></div>
         </div>

        </header>
```

Here background image `background-Mid.bmp` is not coming after deploying it in iis

Comment: i don't know what is going wrong here.Is the path ../ will not work here in IIS

Comment: You getting any `console errors`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally i found solution `@Url.Content(~path to image)` will fix all kinds of issues